# jqgrid - saveRow url throwing an exception

Tags: jqgrid

In inline editing mode, clicking on "Save" is throwing an error.

```
var rowSave = function(id){     
    jQuery("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('saveRow',id,{
        "succesfunc": function(response) {
            return true; 
        },                                  
        "url": myjqgrid.json
        "mtype": "GET"
    });
}
```

**Is it because the `url` is set to `json`?**

Basically, I get JSON response when the grid is loaded the first time. After I edit the row in inline editing mode, the edited data should be sent to the server. When the data is saved on the server, it should return the updated JSON and the grid row data should be updated with the updated JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this doc page:

- http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#saverow

in the section for `saveRow` it says:

> url: if defined, this parameter replaces the editurl parameter from the options array. If set to 'clientArray', the data is not posted to the server but rather is saved only to the grid (presumably for later manual saving).

and a bit below:

> Except when url (or editurl) is 'clientArray', when this method is called, the data from the particular row is POSTED to the server in format name: value, where the name is a name from colModel and the value is the new value.

so it seems you need to supply the server URL that will accept data here. In some of the examples on the same page you can see something like this:

```
...
editurl: "server.php",
...
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I did go through the documentation on wiki. does this mean that in my `rowSave()`, the value of the `url` should be the server side file? and this file will send back JSON? how will the jqgrid get updated?

Comment: This should be the url of the server side page that will accept the data that changed and then e.g. store it in a database or so. You can use `jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('saveRow',"rowid", false, 'clientArray');` variant to do everything locally (i.e. `url` should be `'clientArray'`). When the row is saved, there should be no need for updates from the server, as the state did not change - what kind of update are you expecting to happen? I guess if you just want to reload the grid for some reason, you can use `successfunc` callback.

Comment: data updates. So, if a column in the grid had the value `Client A` but it was edited to `Client B`. I specify the server side page in the `url`. This server side page stores the changed data in the database, spits out the new JSON response. Will the jqgrid automatically pick up the edited data from the JSON response? Does that mean that the value of `url` when (1) first loading the jqgrid and (2) saving the row - should be the same?

Comment: Data updates on the client. Client sends the update to the server. There's no need for server to send any data back to client, as client already knows what was updated. `url` when loading is the url of the page that provides data. `url` when doing `saveRow` is the same as `editurl` in options and that is a different page that should store the data on the server, not produce any data back. If you use `url: 'clientArray'`, all will happen on the client - it will be stored in the grid itself - this emphasizes that it doesn't do any data update from the server when doing `saveRow`.

Comment: I'm not using `clientArray` as I don't want to save the data on the client side. The data should be updated and stored on the server.

Comment: What I'm saying is - imagine you used `clientArray`. This would not go to the server at all. What would you expect to happen to your grid at that point? There are no updates from the server at all, so no updates will happen. Make your application behave as you expect that way and then replace `url` with the actual server url to save the data. I still don't get what you expect to get from the server. If you update a column from `A` to `B`, then do `saveRow`, what do you expect to happen? It should remain `B` and there's no need for server to send any data - client already knows it's `B`.

Comment: client knows that it's `B` but when you refresh the browser, it reverts back to the old data and not the changed data.

Comment: Are you loading the data from the place you saved it? If you are loading the data from the constant json file that is not updated in by the page you point `saveRow` to (via the `url` param we are discussing), it's expected it will not be reflected, as jqGrid will load the data from the same file, which did not change. You need to load the data from the same place where you perform updates, usually a database.

Comment: how else can I simplify what I'm trying to make you understand. You are just talking about the database. I'm talking about JSON that will get updated to reflect the new changed data. My question is how will jqgrid read the changed JSON? Do I need to use `successfunc` and then loop through the JSON file again?

Comment: OK - you have a json file called `myjqgrid.json`. When you use `saveRow`, do you update that file? If you update that very file and then use the very same file when you load your jqGrid, then your data should be saved and loaded as expected on next refresh.

Comment: I'm so glad you now understand what I've been telling you. Yes, the JSON file should be updated when I use `saveRow`. So, in this case what should be the value of `url`? - should it be the server side page or should it be the JSON file?

Comment: It cannot be the json file, it needs to be the active page (e.g. PHP, ASP or whatever) that will need to open that file, change the data as needed and then save the file. There is no need to return anything on the client, no need to do anything in `successfunc`, the client will already be updated. After a browser refresh, if you reference that same file, it will load new data. I think this answers all your concerns.

Comment: do you think you can help me with this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107258/jqgrid-how-to-add-parameters-to-extraparam-of-saverow-in-inline-editing-mode

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help! I don't have ASPX at the moment to work on that, however if you are willing to spend some time reading and trying a few things here and there, you should be able plenty of Net resources to get you started.

Comment: I've been on it for 3 hours now. It doesn't necessarily have to be an .aspx page. It can be any server side page. I just want to figure out how to pass the parameters.