# jqgrid - how to add parameters to extraparam of saveRow in inline editing mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a string:

```
var str = "it's a beautiful day";
```

I am passing this string to the function:

```
rowSave(id, str);
```

**rowSave()**

```
var rowSave = function(id, str){
    jQuery("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('saveRow',id,{
        "succesfunc": function(response) {              
            return true;                
        },                                  
        "url": "server.aspx",
        "mtype": "GET",
        "extraparam": {}
    });
}
```

**What I want to do**

I want to

- split the string based on white space
- every word in the string (after splitting it) should be passed as a parameter in `extraparam` so that it gets appended to the url.

I don't know how to do this.

*As per Oleg's suggestion (see below), added in the `ajaxRowOptions: {cache: false}` in my jqgrid definition.*

```
$("#myjqgrid").jqGrid({
   ajaxRowOptions: {cache: false}
});
```

Comment: The format of `extraparam` is the same as the format of `postData`: you the value is object which has properties like {property1: 'value1', property2: 'value2'}. So you should define in your question not only the values ("every word in the string"), but also the names of the properties. Moreover you wrote that the values should be "appended to the url". The values will be appended to URL only if you use HTTP GET and not in case of HTTP POST for example which is default.

Comment: Additionally you use `"url": server.aspx` which is a syntax error. The  `server.aspx` should be quoted and whether `url` is quoated it doesn't matter. So you should use `url: 'server.aspx'`, `url: "server.aspx"` or `"url": "server.aspx"` instead of `"url": server.aspx`.

Comment: @Oleg: I know the format of `extraparam` and I'm using `GET`. I don't know how to assign the values and different property names after splitting up the string. Is there a way to write a function and loop through them and then assign them. I tried doing it but it's not working.

Comment: Yes, one can do this, but which *names* of the properties you need. I mean that the server part need to know the exact the same name conversion to be able to read this. Are names like `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, ... OK? You can use one parameter instead which just sent the string how it be. Splitting of one parameter with known parameter name can be done much more easy on the server. Is'n so?

Comment: the parameter names can be "A", "B", "C"... actually it needs to be done on the client side. so, it should be in the format -- `"A":"It's", "B":"a", "C":"beautiful", "D":"day"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function similar to the following to build up the extra parameter object:

```
function encodeStr(str){
    var s = str.split(' '), i, result = {};

    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        result['param' + i] = s[i];
    }

    return (result);
}
```

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is used internally by jqGrid and may ensure proper serialization. If you run into problems, use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode each parameter.

Anyway, then just call into this object when you specify your parameters:

```
"extraparam": encodeStr(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code can be about the following:

```js
var rowSave = function(id, str) {
    var strParts = str.split(' '), l = strParts.length, i, obj = {},
        codeStart = 'A'.charCodeAt(0); // 65

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++, codeStart++) {
        obj[String.fromCharCode(codeStart)] = strParts[i];
    }
    $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('saveRow', id, {
        succesfunc: function(response) {
            return true;                
        },                                  
        url: "server.aspx",
        mtype: "GET",
        extraparam: obj
    });
}
```

First the `obj` will be filled as `{A: "it\'s", B: "a", C: "beautiful", D: "day"}` and then it will be used as the value of `extraparam`.

Comment: @SK11: You are welcome! Because you use `mtype: "GET"` you could get problems with caching of the Ajax requests in IE. So I recommend you to use `ajaxRowOptions: {cache: false}` parameter of jqGrid.

Comment: Thank you. I added in the parameter and also updated my post.